# How to add layout_toRightOf dynamically for a button?

Tags: android, android-button

I have a few buttons in my RelativeLayout of activity. But I want also add a button dynamically inside onCreate() so I made something like this:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_start_game);
            ImageButton newbtn1 = new ImageButton(this);
            newbtn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.game_button_2);
            rl.addView(newbtn1);
```

But I also want to set height, width values and the info that my new button sholud be for example right to the buttons which already exist (something like toRightOf inside xml, but now dynamically). Thank you in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

To flesh this out a bit, these are the main sections of the API you will want to focus on.

First, the `addRule(int verb, int anchor)` method:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule(int)

Second, the constants that supply the "verb."

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#constants

You'll do something like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT,WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RIGHT_OF, R.id.some_widget);
params.addRule(ALIGN_RIGHT, R.id.some_other_widget);
newBtn1.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setLayoutParams and pass it a RelativeLayout.LayoutParams object.  It holds all of the to left of, to right of,  etc info.  You'll have to add 1 rule for each of those things you want to add.

Comment: Are you also maybe know if adding alignLeft and alignRight is in the same way, because I forgot to ask about it in my question above?

Comment: Yes.  And width and height are passed into the LayoutParams constructor (and there's special constants for wrapcontent and fillparent).